# Google HTTP Cloud Function returns 403

Tags: google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework

I use serverless framework to manage my cloud functions. Some of them are of HTTP type. Recently, all the HTTP functions started to fail with 403 error. No matter if you enter a URL in a browser or trigger it with the cloud scheduler. The only place where it works is the *testing* tab of the function in the cloud console, when you click the "*Test the function*" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I did not find the reason for the error but it fixed with removing the function and redeploying it.

```
serverless remove
serverless deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the [Identity Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/) has been enabled for the Cloud Function URLs? If you navigate to [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) and then to "Security" and "Identity-Aware Proxy", you should be able to see the IAP settings and whether the Cloud Function is being protected by IAP.

If that is not the cause, I would advise putting some logging in your function that would make it clear whether the function is getting called and then returning a 403 somewhere within the execution of the function (indicating a problem with the function, itself, rather than the identity infrastructure) or if the function is never getting called (the 403 is being produced outside of the Cloud Function), in which case you may need to reach out to Cloud Support for help with this (if IAP isn't the cause).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't see anything related to Cloud Functions listed in IAP.  There only our load balancer.

Comment: Sorry that this did not work. I've updated the question with an additional debugging suggestion; can you determine where the 403 is being generated ... before your function gets invoked or after the function is invoked from within the function?

Comment: For sure 403 happened even before a function is executed because I see no logs in stackdriver. Actually I fixed the problem, but I still don't know what was it)). Will post the answer now.

Comment: What was the solution that fixed your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Functions added some new IAM functionality, not sure how recently, and now new functions don’t have public access by default.

Incase someone else comes here I thought I'd share this information here.

To allow your function to be invoked you first have to add permissions to the function, you can do this by selecting the function in the functions list and adding allUsers to the Cloud Invokes role, you can see the step by step at:

https://lukestoolkit.blogspot.com/2020/06/google-cloud-functions-error-forbidden.html